# GIT menu not visible

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have GIT installed on my desktop. Earlier it used to work fine but on system restart suddenly it stopped working. Usually on right click GIT Clone, GIT Create Repository Here, TortoiseGIt options appear. In my case only TortoiseGIT appears and no further options in it such as Push, Pull, Switch/Checkout etc are visible. In short TortoiseGIT appears but is useless as I cannot do anything. I am using Windows 7 32-bit OS. What could be the cause of this? Also please help solve the issue.

Comment: I think it would be much better to use Git Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you haven't installed a Git for Windows (msysgit): it can preempt those contextual entry menu, as shown in [issue 1995](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1995):

[image: https://tortoisegit.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=19950002001&name=Install-msysGit-004.png&token=xpTmOovltQLaFXvGGSXJmbbQmyc%3A1391411098370&inline=1]

That same case illustrates other poins to check.

> After starting Windows there is no TortoiseGit context menu.
> If I run `cmd.exe` first and then start `explorer.exe` from the project directory, the context menu icons appear again.

The [OP Priyesh Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3192921/priyesh-shah) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520726/git-menu-not-visible/21521564?noredirect=1#comment32494338_21521564):

> I am now able to see the context menu but only on pressing Shift Key+Right Click. Is there some setting to see the context menu without using Shift Key?

That echoes what that issue says:

> Try to Press `SHIFT` and Right Click.
> If TortoiseGit context menu there, please go to **`TortoiseGit -> Settings -> General -> Context Menu ->`** un-check "**`Hide Menus for unversioned paths`**".

---

[John Zabroski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040437/john-zabroski) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520726/git-menu-not-visible/21521564#comment128690811_21521564) to **[TortoiseGit Debuggin Hints](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/master/src/Debug-Hints.txt)**.

Comment: I am now able to see the context menu but only on pressing Shift Key+Right Click. Is there some setting to see the context menu without using Shift Key? Pls help.

Comment: @PriyeshShah I have edited the answer to address your question.

Comment: VonC, any idea what to do when the menu doesn't show at all?  TortoiseGitProc.exe displays a message saying that TortoiseGit should be accessed via File Explorer, so I am not sure how to edit the context menu options when I cant even get the context menu to appear.

Comment: @JohnZabroski I would first try and uninstall/reinstall TortoiseGit in admin mode.

Comment: @VonC I found https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/master/src/Debug-Hints.txt via https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/1995 - I am guessing this latter link is the correct/new link and you should update your post so the link doesn't point to a broken reference.

Comment: @VonC I tried to uninstall and reinstall TortoiseGit in admin mode. It helped slightly, in that after the install completed, explorer.exe didnt die. However, shift+right click still doesnt bring up the TortoiseGit context menus

Comment: @JohnZabroski Thank you. I have included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @JohnZabroski Would a simple right-click be enough in the Windows Explorer? And would the same menu still unavailable after a full reboot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246156/discussion-between-john-zabroski-and-vonc).

Answer (score 1):

I have found my context menu disappears after altering extended menu items (General -> Set Extended Menu Items.) I can reproduce easily by selecting all, for example.

Using Shift + Right-Click as described by VonC, I revisit the settings page, click "Restore Defaults", then "Apply" and the context menu is immediately available with just a Right-Click again.

I'm not certain which extended menu item (or combinations or count) is the issue, but the underlying problem seems to originate here.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me recently and it turned out I had to commit some changes before getting the option back.

[This answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisegit-users/-h-dA2bJWd4/J7nD3DXc_r8J) also states that you should **not** have `Pull` ticked in *both* "Context menu" and "Extended context menu", available in "Settings".