# TortoiseGit Repo-browser context menu not visible

Tags: git, svn, github, tortoisegit

I installed TortoiseGit 1.18.16.0 (X64 bit) in my Windows 8 OS.

When I do right click on TortoiseGit sub-menu, I'm getting only the following options :

1. Settings
2. Help
3. About

whereas `TortoiseSVN -> Repo Browser` menu option is visible.

I even tried enabling the settings dialog of TortoiseGit to enable the `Repo browser` context menu option.  But still I'm not able to view the menu.

However other Git menus [like `Pull`, `Fetch`, `Diff`, `Diff with previous version` etc..,] are visible.

Only this menu remains hidden :( .

Could any one please tell me how to browse the Git repository using TortoiseGit.  Suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[GIT menu not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520726/git-menu-not-visible]) helped me to fix this issue, we need to install the following

1. GIT Bash here and
2. GIT GUI here during the installations.

Once installed these, we need to press 'Shift+ right click to get the menu "GIT Repo-browser" to make visible.

After performing above things, I'm able to view the 'GIT Repo-browser' menu option

[NOTE : Remember the context menu will not be visible for NORMAL RIGHT CLICK instead we need to do a SHIFT + RIGHT CLICK after succesfull installation of Tortoise GIT].

Thanks a lot to Stack Overflow community...!   :)

Answer (score 0):

By defalut, Context Menu should show **Repo-browser**.

In **TortoiseGit -> Settings**, there are two panes for context menu. One is **Context Menu**, the other one is **Set Extend Menu Item**. They have its own **Repo-browser** item.

Make sure you **DO NOT tick `Repo-browser` items both side**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to right-click within a local Git repository, or on its root folder, to see the repo-browser context menu. So make sure you create a local repository first.

Let's say you have:

- `C:\folder_1` (a generic folder)
- `C:\folder_1\folder_2` (a local Git repository under a generic folder)
- `C:\folder_1\folder_2\folder_3` (a folder within your repo)

If you right-click in `C:\folder_1`, you won't see the repo-browser context menu.

If you right-click on `C:\folder_1\folder_2`, or within it (e.g. inside `C:\folder_1\folder_2\folder_3`), you should see the repo-browser context menu.

As noted in [Yue Lin Ho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200710/6096232), make sure your settings are configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to press SHIFT to see it, you can uncheck the Repo-browser option on Settings -> Context Menu 2, this should display your Repo-browser option just doing RIGHT-CLICK (TortoiseGit version 2.8.0.0 64 bits)